# Tomcat servlet "init-parameter" programmatically?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

how to programmatically define init-parameters for a particular servlet? There does not seem to be anything like this in Tomcat API.

```
 org.apache.catalina.Context#addParameter
```

is an equivalent of

```
context-param
```

But there does not seem to be anything like this for the servlet... Am I missing something or this was done for some reason? How to get around this?

I cannot instantiate the servlet class either.

Comment: Servlet container manages the servlets lyfecycle. You shouldn't instatiate servlets manually

Comment: Yeah and I don't want to do that. What I want to do is to specify servlet init-parameter programmatically?

Comment: revise this answer please http://stackoverflow.com/a/13819548/2674303